# Minecraft Code That Gives Player God Like Abilities

Tags: javascript, beginner, minecraft

## Here's Some Context

So I was messing around in *Minecraft* and decided to make some code that basically makes you god. While making the code and testing it I noticed there were some problems that I didn't know how to fix, and came here to see if there were at least a semi-professional coder that could review my code for mistakes or problems.

## What It's Supposed To Do.

This code is made to do the following:

1. Give the player the best equipment, resources, and potion effects possible in *MCPE* (Or *Minecraft Bedrock Edition*).
2. Give the best possible enchantments to the player on the requested piece of equipment.
3. Re-give the player their potion effects.

## What It Does

It tends to work **most** of the time, but, I've noticed that it only occasionally does the following things: 1. Only applies certain affects, 2. Only gives certain items while leaving some out, and 3. Sometimes doesn't apply the enchantments on the requested item.

## How the code is run (How I Run it)

I have the *Minecraft* world where I test my code open. Here when I finish the code on the coding application I'm using I will press the big green "Run Program" button which in this case is just a preparatory command which makes sure that when I type the required message it will go through each line of code, and step by step, complete each of the given tasks. To better help those who may not understand I have taken some screenshots of the basic process.

[image: Random code I made in the program.]

[image: The program's run button.]

[image: The program's executionary command that enables the random code to start running.]

[image: The result after the program is done running the random code.]

## The Code in JavaScript

```
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "fire protection",
    4
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "thorns",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("Enchant my helmet", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "projectile protection",
    4
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "respiration",
    5
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "aqua affinity",
    1
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "thorns",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("i want zombies", function () {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        mobs.spawn(mobs.monster(ZOMBIE), pos(0, 0, 0))
    }
})
player.onChat("i wanna be god", function () {
    mobs.applyEffect(REGENERATION, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 255)
    mobs.applyEffect(STRENGTH, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(HEALTH_BOOST, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 74)
    mobs.applyEffect(JUMP_BOOST, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(SPEED, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(ABSORPTION, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(HASTE, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(WATER_BREATHING, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(FIRE_RESISTANCE, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(RESISTANCE, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(NIGHT_VISION, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    gameplay.setGameRule(NATURAL_REGENERATION, true)
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    DIAMOND_SWORD,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    BOW,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    DIAMOND_PICKAXE,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    DIAMOND_AXE,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    DIAMOND_SHOVEL,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    TORCH,
    128
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    COOKED_BEEF,
    200
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    ENCHANTED_APPLE,
    64
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    DIAMOND_HELMET,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    ELYTRA,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    DIAMOND_LEGGINGS,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    DIAMOND_BOOTS,
    1
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    ARROW,
    128
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    ENCHANTED_APPLE,
    64
    )
    mobs.give(
    mobs.target(ALL_PLAYERS),
    BOW,
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("Creepers", function () {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        mobs.spawn(mobs.monster(SPIDER), pos(0, 0, 0))
    }
})
player.onChat("Enchant my shovel", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "effeciency",
    5
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "fortune",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "silk touch",
    1
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("i want my effects back", function () {
    mobs.applyEffect(REGENERATION, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 255)
    mobs.applyEffect(STRENGTH, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(HEALTH_BOOST, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 74)
    mobs.applyEffect(JUMP_BOOST, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(SPEED, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(ABSORPTION, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(HASTE, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(WATER_BREATHING, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(FIRE_RESISTANCE, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(RESISTANCE, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
    mobs.applyEffect(NIGHT_VISION, mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER), 600, 4)
})
player.onChat("i want spiders", function () {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        mobs.spawn(mobs.monster(SPIDER), pos(0, 0, 0))
    }
})
player.onChat("Enchant my boots", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "protection",
    4
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "feather falling",
    4
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "depth strider",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "frost walker",
    2
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "thorns",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("Enchant my axe", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "smite",
    5
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "effeciency",
    5
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "fortune",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("Enchant my sword", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "fire aspect",
    2
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "knockback",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "looting",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "sharpness",
    5
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("Enchant my pick", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "effeciency",
    5
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "fortune",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("Enchant my chesplate", function () {
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "blast protection",
    4
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "thorns",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "unbreaking",
    3
    )
    mobs.enchant(
    mobs.target(LOCAL_PLAYER),
    "mending",
    1
    )
})
player.onChat("i want skeletons", function () {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        mobs.spawn(mobs.monster(SKELETON), pos(0, 0, 0))
    }
})
```

## Friendly Reminder

If you wish to edit this question please don't change too much. Just do things like correct grammar and formatting.

Comment: Why do you think someone will edit out all the content?

Comment: @Penguin I don't think they will edit out all content I'm just politely asking that if they do edit out content that they do edit TOO much as to keep the message basically the same.